# Google Reverse Image Search against private S3 images?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-search, google-image-search

I am attempting to reverse search images contained within a *private* Amazon AWS S3 bucket. The URL is of the format;

```
https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=BUCKET_URL
```

where

```
    BUCKET_URL = https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/image/folder/cat.jpg?
Expires=1494399999&AWSAccessKeyId=AKey&Signature=GenSig
```

I receive this error message;

> The URL doesn't refer to an image or the image is not publicly
>   accessible.

If;

- Signed URL via browser - **Success**
- Reverse search unsigned public object url - **Success**
- Reverse search signed public object url - **Fail**
- Reverse search signed private object url - **Fail**
- Reverse search unsigned private object url - **Fail *(As expected)***

It seems that the signing of the URL is preventing reverse search from accessing the resource, even if it is public in the bucket, and accessible unsigned.

Any idea why this is happening, or how I can fix it?

Comment: What if you properly URL-escape the `&` symbols to `%26`? *e.g.* `...byimage?&image_url=https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/image/folder/cat.jpg?
Expires=1494399999%26AWSAccessKeyId=AKey%26Signature=GenSig`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Michael-sqlbot, but unfortunately the issue persists after escaping &. The image is still directly accessible in the browser using the escaped url.

Comment: Worth a shot.  Let's try a different approach.  What's the motivation for trying to search against an image in a private bucket?  Describe your use case, please... there may be a workaround.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have a bunch of low quality images (200x200px - 1,000x1,000px), and I need to increase their quality by finding higher res versions

Comment: What about a (temporary) bucket policy to allow dowloads based on [`Condition: {"StringLike": {"aws:UserAgent": "Google*"}}`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition) or whatever specific User-Agent string is used by image search?  If your content is sensitive, that wouldn't be appropriate, but otherwise... maybe?